# How to get the content of a file with a URL encoded '%' in the ID?

Tags: request, odata

Ok, so I got this random problem, where I got an object with the ID '**%252F1.wav**'.

Usually when calling the object, I would type in the following GET Request:

```
https://randomOdataService.com/items/Item('12345')
```

However, when doing the same with the ID '**%252F1.wav**' I just receive a code 404. But the object definitively is there:

```
{
      "createdAt": "2022-07-14T12:15:07.861Z",
      "createdBy": "anonymous",
      "modifiedAt": "2022-07-14T12:15:07.861Z",
      "modifiedBy": "anonymous",
      "ID": "%252F1.wav",
      "title": null,
      "Category_ID": null,
      "tags": null
}
```

How do I need to change my GET Request to get to the content/delete it?

Comment: You need to decode the %-encoding: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding %XX means the hex value XX

Comment: Obvious approach would be to try both `%2F1.wav` and `%25252F1.wav`, depending on whether you need to *not* encode the percent, or encode it *again* (which will depend on the API and your client).

Comment: Can you update your question to include what your URL looks like with the `%252F1.wav` file just so it's not ambiguous? I'm guessing you should be passing up `%25252F1.wav` as @JeroenMostert suggested.

Comment: @Brad you guys were right. As @JeroenMostert suggested I tried the `%25252F1.wav` which worked